JUnit Test Case For Private void Methods
I want to write test case for private void method of injected mock class, but found no way to do that. Although on reading similar problems found that private method should not be invoked in test cases. But For sonar covergae i need to do that. Please provide some way to Either exclude specifically those methds form sonar covergae or how can i write test case for private void methods?
Tried mocking the same class which is (InjectMock or Autowired) didn't work.

Test the methods that call those private methods. If those aren't called during tests you have missing test cases. Don't call private methods from tests instead use the public API and supply appropriate usecases to cover the private methods as well.

Worked sonar coverage is incresed.

If you have a private method, it's likely being called from some other public method, so adding test case for that public method should give you the line coverage .
